# Hibernate: Mapping single column to different tables

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I am having the following tables:

```
Template(
Template_Id,
Template_Name,
Component_Type,
Component_Id
)

Division(
Division_Id,
Division_Name
)

SubDivision(
SubDivision_Id,
SubDivision_Name
)

Department(
Department_Id,
Department_Name
)
```

In the Template table, the Component_Type field can contain the value Division or SubDivision or Department.

Component_Id will contain Division_Id or SubDivision_Id or Depatment_Id depending on Component_Type.

I am aware that the Template table is not completely normalized and it would be better to have different tables like Template_Division, Template_SubDivision etc...
However, these are existing tables and we cannot modify them.

My question is,
How should I configure the Component_Id column in Template class?

Template.java will look like the following:-

```
public class Template{

@Id
@Column(name="Template_Id)
private Long id;

@Column(name="Template_Name)
private String name;

@Column(name="Component_Type")
private String componentType; 

}
```

Can someone please explain how to configure the Component_Id column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`@Any` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-hibspec-singleassoc-any). Note that since Hibernate 3.5 you have to access Hibernate via `Session` interface (i.e. not `EntityManager`) in order to use it.